# Windows Phone MediaElement throws Object Reference

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone Application with Hub and HubSections.
Here is my code:

```
        <Hub Header="Music" Margin="0,93.167,0,10" Grid.Row="1" SectionsInViewChanged="SectionsInViewChanged">
        <HubSection Header="Immediate Music" Name="DarkSideofPowerHubSection" Height="528" MinWidth="250">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,330" Text="Dark Side of Power" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="0,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="341" Source="Assets/Time_Will_Remember_Us.jpg"/>
                    <MediaElement AutoPlay="False" Name="Music" Source="Assets/Sounds/Dark_Side_of_Power.mp3" Margin="10,50,150,150"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

My problem is that I cant access the variable Music in my code. Also the MediaElement line is underlined and says: "Object reference not set to an object."

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or if I cant use a MediaElement inside a HubSection?

Thanks,

Claor

Comment: Search SO on how to access elements that are part of a `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Music"></MediaElement>
```

outside the hub, instead inside the datatemplate